# cakePhp and a foreign key : i cannot write the foreign key in the view

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

i've got a problem with a foreign key field : i created a `categories` table with `MySQLWorkbench`, which is linked by a `1:n` relation to another table : `Articles`. It seems to work, because in `Articles`, there is a `categories_id` "INT" field .

I baked the whole project, everything works fine, except this foreign key : instead of an input that would receive the "number" i would write to specify the `categories_id` number, there is a kind of empty "select" (list) that contains nothing, so i cannot enter any number for the `categories_id` field in my database :

here's the image :
[image: my categories input]

If i try to "force" and add an "article" (so without the category), there is this error :

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecommerce`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_articles_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`categories_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

And here's my **`add.ctp`** file (it is written `input` for the `categories_id`, so i don't know what to change) :

```
<div class="articles form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Article');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Article'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('nom');
        echo $this->Form->input('prix');
        echo $this->Form->input('categories_id');
    ?>
```

Thanks for your help

---

EDIT:

here's what i added :

```
class Article extends AppModel {

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className'    => 'Category',
            'foreignKey'    => 'category_id'
         )
    );
}
```

and :

```
class Category extends AppModel {

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'className'    => 'Article',
            'foreignKey'    => 'category_id'
         )
    );
}
```

and in the controller (`add()`) :

```
public function add() {
        //$this->set('categories',$this->Article->Category->find('all'));
        //$c = $this->Article->Category->find('all', array("recursive"=>-1, 'fields'=>array('id', 'nom')));
        $c = $this->Article->Category->find('list');
        $this->set('cat', $c);
```

but in my view, `pr($cat)` returns an empty Array...

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('nom');
    echo $this->Form->input('prix');
    echo $this->Form->input('category_id', array('option'=>$cat));
            pr($cat);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the naming convention.. if your table is called `categories` then the foreign key in `articles` should be `category_id` (singular) and the model must be called `Category`. The controller should pass to the view a variable called '$categories' (plurar)

`$this->set('categories',$this->Article->Category->find('list'))`

and the input in the view has to be:

`echo $this->Form->input('category_id');`

don't forget to change the foreign key in the model too

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "if your model is called Categories" => you mean `Category` (singular) or `table` instead of `model`

Comment: @pleasedontbelong : thanks, where should i put this : `$this->set('categories',$this->Article->Category->find('list'));` ? in `ArticlesController` > `add` ? it doesn't work (because of "find" called on a non-object...). Any other idea? and can you explain me why you'd call "find list" ? thanks again

Comment: yes it should be in ArticlesController/add(). It's not working because you need to [declare the relation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) between Article and Category in the Article Model, or if you prefer you can [load the model in the controller](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllerloadModel) or add 'Category' in the [$uses attribute](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) to load that Model

Comment: @pleasedontbelong : thanks pleasedontbelong, i edited my first post to show you the code, i added the different variables (belongsTo and hasMany) i don't have the fatal error on `find` anymore, but i still have this empty select as shown in the image above... (and in the code, `pr($cat)` just returns an empty array...) any idea?

Comment: do the pr($c) in the controller.. try doing a find('all') instead (just to test) check that you have categories in your database... if you're still getting an empty array it beacause there's something wrong on your code.. tables not following the naming convention, or something like that... that's why i always bake the code before coding :) so i dont have to deal with this kind of problems

Comment: @pleasedontbelong : thanks pleasedontbelong, i'm getting close, the pr actually contains my categories, so it works, but those categories don't want to show up in the "select" in my view, it is just an empty "select", but it's the same variable `$cat` used for both of them (the pr and the `find ('list ', array ... id, name)` ... something else i could try ? thanks again

Comment: when passing the variable to the view, if you name the variable "categories" instead of "cat", cake will automatically fill the select. But if you want to manually create the select from an array you need to add the ´options´ to the input (you have a typo in the view). The array you give in options should be a simple "key-value" array, that's why you should use ´find('list')´ instead of ´find('all')´. If you're still having problem, my advice would be to [generate the code using bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) :) good luck

Comment: @pleasedontbelong : thank you so much! alright it works fine with `$categories` ! if you still have the courage to answer to this question i would really appreciate, you said, i have to use an option array, which i did in my view: `input('category_id', array('option'=>$cat));` , and in the cookbook : http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data no more about "options". So i guess it's in the view, so did i make any mistake in my previous code? Thanks again anyway, it finally works :)

Comment: you had a typo in your code.. you wrote `array('option'=>$cat));` and it should be `array('options'=>$cat));`, i guess it was that

Comment: @pleasedontbelong : sorry i forgot to thank you, thanks man! i appreciated your help! Bye!